# How to execute script using executeScript on newly created tabs in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm trying to create a new tab, then execute a trivial code in it (i.e. an alert). 
I'm using [`executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method for this [`programmatic Injection`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) operation. 
The tab is created successfully, but the alert is not displayed !

manifest.json

```
{
    "name" : "TabCreatorAlerter",
    "description" : "Opens a tab and shows an alert in it !",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "permissions" : ["tabs"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.create(
    {url:"http://www.google.com"},
    function(createdTab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            createdTab.id, 
            {code:"alert('hi');"} 
        );
    }
);
```

What is wrong with this code ? and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the `*://www.google.com/*` permission to the manifest file.

If you look at your [background page's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029), you would have seen the error. Or, look at [chrome.runtime.lastError](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-lastError) in the callback of [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript):

```
chrome.tabs.create(
    {url:"http://www.google.com"},
    function(createdTab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            createdTab.id, 
            {code:"alert('hi');"},
            function() {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: The use of chrome.runtime.lastError which you provided is very helpful too, Thanks !

Comment: I'm injecting code on a newly created tab as well, but the tab is an extension's page (with the url like: chrome-extension://fvdv...gdfg/page.html) but it is telling me  that on the manifest I should add permission for that host. What should I add? so far I have permissions for ['contextMenus', 'tabs', '*://*/*']

Comment: @Alex There is no permission to get access to the NTP if it is another extension page.

Comment: Thank you Rob, so what error is it throwing and what am I supposed to do..? Cannot I inject code in a tab I created?

Comment: Is it *your* extension page? If so, use `chrome.extension.getViews`